# How to calculate $\Delta Y$ given $\Delta X$, a simple linear equation, and a correlation score?

Tags: regression, arithmetic

Suppose I conduct a correlation and SLR analysis on a bivariate data set and obtain the following:
$$r=.63$$

$$Y=2.1+5.6X$$

If I increase X by 300, how much will Y go up?

Comment: Note that the correlation coefficient is a distraction in your question; you do not use it in the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You got the regression equation given by $Y = 2.1+5.6*X$

So, put $x = 300$ in the regression equation, you get

$Y = 2.1 + 5.6*300 = 2.1+ 1680 = 1682.1$

So, the $Y$ go up by 1680 units. Otherwise, the answer $Y = 1682.1$ is the estimated value when $X = 300$

Answer (score 0):

Coefficient that stands with $X$ in your equation tells you how much $Y$ will go up when $X$ goes up by 1.

Since this coefficient is 5.6, you may say that if you incerease $X$ by 1, $Y$ will go up by 5.6.

So if you incerease $X$ by 300, $Y$ will go up by $5.6 \cdot 300 = 1680$.